# Pass an array of valid values to Joi.valid()

Tags: joi

I'm tyring to valid `req.body`, and the valid values is one item from the array.

Is there a way to do that?

Code:

```
updatePersonSchema = Joi.object({
    personName: Joi.string().min(2).required(),
    updateFiled: Joi.string().valid(personParams).required(), //oneOf the personParams
    value: Joi.required()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can pass an array to a valid function like this

```js
const personParams = ['name', 'email', 'password']

updatePersonSchema = Joi.object({
    personName: Joi.string().min(2).required(),
    updateFiled: Joi.string().valid(...personParams).required(), //oneOf the personParams
    value: Joi.required()
})
```